# Host Django application in the Lightsail's built in Apache server

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I want to have a production ready Django app with Lighsail and for that I'm following two tutorials to achieve this

- [Deploy Django-based application onto Amazon Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-python-application/)
- [Deploy A Django Project](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/)

From the Bitnami article can see that the AWS documentation follows its [Approach B: Self-Contained Bitnami Installations](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/#approach-b-self-contained-bitnami-installations).

According to:

- AWS's documentation, my blocker appears in *5. Host the application using Apache, step g*.
- Bitnami's documentation, where it says

> On Linux, you can run the application with mod_wsgi in daemon mode.
> Add the following code in
> /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/PROJECT/conf/httpd-app.conf:

The blocker relates to the code I'm being asked to add, in particular the final part that has

```
Alias /tutorial/static "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.9-py3.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/static"
WSGIScriptAlias /tutorial '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/tutorial/tutorial/wsgi.py'
```

More specifically, `/home/bitnami/apps/django/`. In `/home/bitnami/` can only see the following folders
. bitnami_application_password
. bitnami_credentials
. htdocs
. stack

and from them the one that most likely resembles `/opt/bitnami/apps/` is `/home/bitnami/stack/`. Thing is, inside of that particular folder, there's no django folder - at least as far as I can tell (already checked inside some of its folders, like the python one).

The workaround for me at this particular stage is to move to a different approach, [Approach A: Bitnami Installations Using System Packages](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/#approach-a-bitnami-installations-using-system-packages) (which I've done and managed to make it work as wrote in [this blog post](https://weblog.tiagoperes.eu/production-ready-django-app-in-amazon-lighsail/)), but I'd like to get it to work using Approach B and hence this question.

Comment: You are mixing the `/opt/bitnami` folder and the `/home/bitnami` one. In the `/home/bitnami` folder, you find the files you mentioned in your message but the `/opt/bitnami` folder contains all the files of the installation. Please follow the documentation (Approach B in your case) to add the pending configuration lines to the Apache's configuration

Comment: @JotaMartos the files for configuration (python, apache, apache2, ...) are in /home/bitnami/stack/ but there's no django there

Comment: You are using the latest Bitnami Django version so you need to follow the ["Approach A" guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/#approach-a-bitnami-installations-using-system-packages) in our documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in the mentioning of the paths for both the project and Django.

[image: Actual Bitnami folder]

In my case, projects are under `/home/bitnami/projects/` where I created a Django project named tutorial.

Also, if I run the command

```
python -c "
import sys
sys.path = sys.path[1:]
import django
print(django.__path__)"
```

it'll print me the location where Django is installed

> ['/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django']

[image: Bitnami opt folder not as expected]

So, the httpd-app.conf should have instead at the end

```
Alias /tutorial/static "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static"
WSGIScriptAlias /tutorial '/home/bitnami/projects/tutorial/tutorial/wsgi.py'
```