# Restart Apache in Lightsail Terminal

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, apache, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

As I found a blocker in one [approach to make a Django app production ready](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64117945/5675325) I've gone with a different approach [documented here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/).

In particular, this question is about [this step](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/#enable-predefined-virtual-hosts-for-a-django-project) where it says «Restart Apache for the changes to be taken into effect» and has the following associated command

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Thing is, ctlscript.sh isn't in that folder but in /opt/bitnami/stack. Then, when running in that forder

```
sudo ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

I get this error

> sudo: ctlscript.sh: command not found

[image: Lightsail restart Apache]

The file is there so I thought it would be something related with permissions (as pointed [here](https://community.bitnami.com/t/opt-bitnami-ctlscript-sh-command-not-found/63180/4?u=brotherperes)).

The script is in the right folder, so the problem points to incorrect permissions.

```
sudo chmod 755 ctlscript.sh
```

but running the command to restart Apache got me into the same "command not found" error.

[image: Lightsail can't restart Apache]

Comment: This question is really unrelated to any of the tags you have added to it. It's just a basic `linux` path question.

Comment: @MarkB it relates to the other tags due to the base documentation which has particular mistakes (path wise).

Comment: @MarkB this is a particular Django instance created in Lightsail together with Bitnami. As Bitnami shifts their folder structures, AWS's documentation gets this mistakes and it ceases from being updated. I'm not sure the same is necessarily happening with other instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"command not found" does not point to "incorrect permissions". You're getting errors because the script is not in your `PATH`. There's two ways you can go this

1. Discover and specify the full path.
2. Specify the current directory.

---

### Method 1

Run

```
pwd
```

and you will get the full path. If you get `/home/bitnami/stack`, then, run

```
sudo /home/bitnami/stack/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

[image: Amazon Lightsail restart Apache]

---

### Method 2

Run

```
sudo ./ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

and that will work too

[image: Amazon Lightsail restart Apache]

Comment: Doing that I get `sudo: /opt/bitnami/stack/ctlscript.sh: command not found`. As you can see in the first image, the script is in that location I'm at

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 All I can see from the screenshot is that you are in `~/stack`. Is your home directory `/opt/bitnami`? What folder does it say you are in when you run the `pwd` command? How about just specifying the current directory via `sudo ./ctlscript.sh restart apache`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (I was getting a command not found error too):

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Taken from https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/administration/control-services/